# jQuery :has(.something:contains()) unsupported?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the HTML below, I am trying to use jQuery to match all the **list items** that have a span with the class "foo" and that span should contain the text "relevant".

```
<ul> 
  <li>Some text <span class="foo">relevant</span></li> 
  <li>Some more text <span class="foo">not</span> <span class="bar">relevant</span></li> 
  <li>Even more <span class="foo">not so either</span></li> 
  <li>Blablabla <span class="foo">relevant</span> <span class="bar">blabla</span></li> 
  <li>No foo here <span class="bar">relevant</span></li> 
</ul>
```

Note that there are also a few span's with the class "bar", and that also has the text "relevant", that should not be included.

My attempts at a selector:

```
ul li:has(.foo:contains('relevant"))
```

This does not work. The next example selects something, but does not take into account that there are multiple span's inside the list:

```
ul li:has(span:contains('relevant"))
```

[Here is a live example that you can play with](http://jsbin.com/utezi). In a working version, only the first and fourth elements of that list should be selected.

Comment: +1 for using jsbin in the question, saving us all work time.

Comment: @Kobi - +1 for admitting you SO at work :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this out:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span.foo:contains(relevant)').parents('li').each(function() {
       alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: That selects the span.foo, not the list item.

Answer (score 4):

Beaten to it...  But if you want a pure selector you were darn close

```
ul li:has(span[class='foo']:contains('relevant'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reverse the order of the selectors:

```
$("ul li:has(:contains('relevant').foo)").css('background-color', 'red');
```

This seems to work well, can't say why though: http://jsbin.com/asoma

Answer (score 1):

I know this may not be as elegant, but at least it'll work:

```
$("ul li .foo:contains('relevant')").parent("li");
```

I couldn't get your version to work either...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're having that problem with the selector, confirmed this does work though:

```
$("ul li").filter(":has(span.foo:contains('relevant'))").css('background-color', 'green');
```